# Remove value from NSMutableDictionary() according to Firebase value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

I define `var dictImages = NSMutableDictionary()` to store downloaded images and to not load more than one time, but when I remove row from `tableView` in `Firebase`, images are sliding. I figured out that problem is in `dictImages`. The only way to prevent that error is to write

```
dictImages.removeAllObjects()
```

before downloading images, but in this case there is no meaning of storing images and it is not efficient. I need to figure out previously stored item and remove it.

This code is written in `cellForRowAt` function of `tableView` :

```
if let image = self.dictImages.object(forKey: indexPath)
    {
        cell?.newsImg.image = image as? UIImage
    }
    else{
    storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            if let data = data
            {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                self.dictImages.setObject(image, forKey: indexPath as NSCopying)
                cell?.newsImg.image = image
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Before removing row]

[image: After removing row]

Comment: images are sliding... unable to understand term 'sliding' in context of images. Please explain more what is happening in UI when you delete a row from tableView.

Comment: I have added images to the post. Maybe it would help to describe issue

Comment: Unrelated but don't use `NSMutable...` types in Swift at all. Use native types.

Comment: You have added code for add image in the question. What have you done for removing row from `tableView`

Comment: Instead of dictionary, use array of images based on indexPath, otherwise you have to re structure your dictionary every time when removing value. Array is more suitable for you in this situation.